# Best way to reuse test data in several pytest tests?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I need to run a number of tests using pytest.
Several tests rely on data which must be read from a database, and which takes a while to retrieve.
For this reason, I would like to construct a testing dataset once, then reuse it in several tests.

I would do something like the below to accomplish this. Is this a reasonable way to reuse testing data, or should I do something else?

```
from copy import deepcopy


def read_test_data():
    # Takes a while to run
    return test_data


reusable_test_data = read_test_data()


def get_test_data():
    # Using this helper method to make sure no test accidentally modifies the test data
    return deepcopy(reusable_test_data)


def test_foo():
    data = get_test_data()
    # Test something

def test_bar():
    data = get_test_data()
    # Test something else
```

Comment: You could make the ```data``` variable global, so place it outside the scope of ```test_foo``` and ```test_bar```. This way you can pass ```data``` as an argument, which reuses the data.

Comment: The pytest way would be to use a session-scoped fixture for that.